# Is there a way to get Maven to install javadocs for all dependencies to my local repo?

Tags: maven-2, maven, javadoc

By running `mvn dependency:sources` I can force maven to resolve all dependencies in my project, download the sources, and install them into my local repo.

**Is there something that does the same thing with my dependencies' JavaDocs?**  I.e. grab them from upstream repos and install them into my local repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do it with the [`eclipse:eclipse`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) mojo using the [`downloadJavadocs`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#downloadJavadocs) parameter.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadJavadocs
```

And if you don't use eclipse, just do

```
mvn eclipse:clean
```

afterwards.

It's a hack, I know, but it works.

---

Actually, [`dependency:sources`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html) pretends to be configurable through the [`classifier`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html#classifier) and [`type`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html#type) parameters, so for a moment I thought you could do this:

```
mvn dependency:sources -Dclassifier=javadoc -Dtype=jar
```

but I tried it and it didn't work. Then I checked the source code and found this:

```
private static final String SOURCE_TYPE = "java-source";
private static final String SOURCE_CLASSIFIER = "sources";

// ...

public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException
{
    // parameters are overwritten with constant values
    this.classifier = SOURCE_CLASSIFIER;
    this.type = SOURCE_TYPE;
```

I have now [submitted a Bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-298) concerning this.

Comment: Nice.  And +1 for the "it's a hack" confession.